# group not exported from d3-array

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I npm installed d3-array (v2.4.0) and want to import the group function with

`import { group } from "d3-array"`

But this generates an error:

`Attempted import error: 'group' is not exported from 'd3-array'.`

The installed module seems fine: I see the group function in dist/d3-array.js, and it also exported. So I don't understand why I can't import it.
It seems other functions are also not exported. There are some 45 functions in d3-array, but when I log the module, I only get some 32 of them:

````
bisect: (...)
bisectRight: (...)
bisectLeft: (...)
ascending: (...)
bisector: (...)
cross: (...)
descending: (...)
deviation: (...)
extent: (...)
histogram: (...)
thresholdFreedmanDiaconis: (...)
thresholdScott: (...)
thresholdSturges: (...)
max: (...)
mean: (...)
median: (...)
merge: (...)
min: (...)
pairs: (...)
permute: (...)
quantile: (...)
range: (...)
scan: (...)
shuffle: (...)
sum: (...)
ticks: (...)
tickIncrement: (...)
tickStep: (...)
transpose: (...)
variance: (...)
zip: (...)```

I ran into this issue before, I was able to solve it by downgrading to d3-array 2.3.3. But that solution is not working for me anymore.
````

Comment: Do you have d3 in your depencencies? 

I also wanted to use `group` from d3-array, but had the same problem. 

In my dependencies was `"d3": "^5.7.0"`, which uses `d3-array@1` (in my case `1.2.4` from looking at yarn.lock).

Explicitly requiring `d3-array`, `group` is now exported.